# How to kill MY OWN idle ssh sessions

Tags: linux, ssh, process, kill

I have a few idle ssh sessions that I want to kill. This remote server is used by many users, how do I identify the pids of the sessions that I own?

When I run `who`, I get a list of ssh sessions labeled by username.

```
$ who
                                                                                       
me      pts/0        2020-11-23 18:05 (tmux(id).%0)
me      pts/1        2020-11-06 13:28 (<ip 1>)
someone    pts/2        2020-11-09 09:36 (<ip 2>)
someone    pts/3        2020-11-26 20:26 (<ip 2>)
...
```

When I run `pstree`, the sessions are no longer labeled by username.

```
$ pstree -p | grep sshd 

|-sshd(930)-+-sshd(3518)---sshd(3536)---python(5736)-+-{python}(5744)
           |           |-sshd(4285)---sshd(4308)
           |           |-sshd(5428)---sshd(5450)
...
```

Answer (score 5):

Unless you are the root user, you will not be able to do anything to anybody else's processes, so there's no danger in just signalling all `sshd` processes:

```
pkill sshd
```

If you want to explicitly limit this to your own processes:

```
pkill -U "$USER" sshd
```

or, if the `USER` variable isn't used in the shell that you are running, try `"$LOGNAME"` in place of `"$USER"`, or

```
pkill -U "$(id -un)" sshd
```

See also the manual for the `pkill` command.

Use `pgrep` instead of `pkill` if you want to get a list of the process IDs of the matched processes.  Use `pkill` or `pgrep` with `-o` to only signal or list the *oldest* process.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. And when I run ```pkill sshd```, will that kill the ssh session I'm currently running the command from? And will that also permanently kill my tmux sessions?

Comment: @user443888 It would send the `TERM` signal to all `sshd` processes that you own. I'm unsure whether that would kill `tmux`, but I don't _think_ so. It would be fairly easy to test (on my OpenBSD system, it does not kill `tmux` and I doubt it would do on Linux).

Answer (score 0):

If you are `root`, don't run `pkill sshd` on a remote server, or you won't be able to reconnect: `ssh: connect to host yourdomain.com port 22: Connection refused`. Instead:

1. Run `w`. Find your idle command in the last column (labeled `WHAT`). Then look at the second column (labeled `TTY`) to find your idle session, ex: `pts/0`.
2. Run `ps aux | grep pts/0`. Find your idle command in the last column - its PID will be in the second column, ex: `12345`. Also look for `-bash` and note its PID, ex: `12346`.
3. Run `kill 12345; kill 12346` with the PIDs from above.
4. Rerun `w`. `pts/0` should no longer show.

Comment: You won't be able to reconnect after `pkill sshd` if `pkill` kills the `sshd` process which happens to be the daemon. Usually the daemon runs as root, regular users cannot `kill`/`pkill` it, they can only kill `sshd` processes they own. Compare [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/703045/108618). Your answer is relevant if one logs in via SSH as root and if one wants to kill root's sessions; then yes, it's easy to kill the daemon as well. Some systems/setups disallow logging in via SSH as root, the problem does not exist there. Regular users can `pkill sshd` and the daemon will survive.