# Why does running sudo systemctl stop ssh over ssh not immediately terminate the ssh session

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

This question stems out of curiosity, but lets say I currently have an ssh session with a remote computer, and I run the following command:

`sudo systemctl stop ssh`

and after running:

`systemctl status ssh`

to verify the status of the service, it seems to be inactive(dead)
why am I still able to execute any commands remotely?

again this is not a formal problem, I am just curious

Thank You for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you connect, the SSH daemon (e.g. `sshd`) forks at least once. From now on your connection is handled by a separate process, not *the* listening daemon itself.

`systemctl stop ssh` stops the listening daemon, so new SSH connections cannot be established. Existing connections survive because forked processes survive.

This is an example snippet from `pstree -u`:

```
systemd-+-…
        …
        |-sshd---sshd---sshd(kamil)---bash---…
        …
```

The first `sshd` is the daemon running as root. The second one is a forked elevated process, still retaining root's power. The third one has dropped root's power, it belongs to me (kamil). Stopping (killing) the daemon process does not affect the other two (yes, I have tested).