# Reboot only if no ssh session are active

Tags: systemd, sshd, reboot

I'm trying to think of a solution for a problem I have.
I have a server running sftp.
I sometime need to reboot this machine for updates and other maintenance but I don't want to wait for the precise moment it's inactive to run the reboot command. I'd like to be able to ask the server to reboot and wait for its last ssh connection to be active ended (if it can refuse new connection it would be a plus but it's not necessary).
Can I configure `systemd` or `ssh` so that `sshd` will suspend the reboot process as long as active connections are running toward the server.
This imply at least keeping my mount point, network, and ssh daemon running until active ssh session stop at which point the machine can restart.
I'm looking for a solution using either sshd or systemd configuration.
If the solution is a custom script I'll work on that but I would love to have an integrated solution.

Comment: "if it can refuse new connection it would be a plus" – You refuse new SSH connections simply by stopping the relevant service. [Existing connections will not be terminated automatically](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703040/108618). If you do this locally, you're safe. If you do this via SSH and your connection breaks then you will lock yourself out. I guess in this case a safer approach is to [temporarily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/727443/108618) add `AllowUsers your_login` to `sshd_config`, so even if something goes wrong you will be able to log in.

Comment: Opposite: [How to solve the problem "User xxx is logged in on sshd“ when using shutdown close linux server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/744340/108618). Maybe you need to enable what the other asker needs to disable. IMO it's good to link both questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the server over SSH and see if anyone is logged in using the command `who`  or the command `w`

```bash
if [[ -z $(ssh SERVERHOST-IP 'w -oh') ]]; then echo "No User Logged in"; else echo "User Connected"; fi
```

This will check if the command `w -oh` is empty which will check if any user is logged in.

You can use this to restart your server remotely when no more users are logged in.

```shell
while [ $(ssh SERVERHOST-IP 'w -oh|wc -l') -gt 0 ]; do sleep 1; echo "User Connected"; done && echo "Reboot server" && ssh -t SERVERHOST-IP 'sudo shutdown -r now'
```

- You may omit the `echo` commands if you prefer.
- Replace `SERVERHOST-IP` with your actual server IP address or hostname.
- `who`, `w` and `wc` are common commands in Linux and are most likely available to you.

You could use any of these command to:

1. Create a custom shutdown command placed in `/usr/sbin`
2. Create a custom `systemd` shutdown routine

Comment: Thank you this is an interesting solution but if I have to script that I will use python. I do not want to maintains a bash script.