# Set sshd to refuse new connection

Tags: systemd, sshd

I have a busy server with lots of connection.
When I want to plan a reboot I'd like to set SSH to refuse new connection until the machine restarted.
Is there such an option in the sshd deamons ? I couldn't find one.
Maybe the easiest way to do so is to use `iptables`.
How would you achieve this goal ?

Comment: [Just stop the daemon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/703040/108618).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski , Thank you very much, I would accept that as a solution.
This is exactly what I want to achieve.

Comment: in iptables, just add ad beginning of INPUT that NEW connections are REJECT, if you have ESTABLISHED and RELATED already in the tables. (so you block only new connections)

Comment: Just for community sake, yes there's already an explication to what to do but not in the context of what I want to do. 
I want to put a proper answer to my questino because the phrasing should be adapted to the quesiton and should not necessitate the person to switch phrasing it makes for very unreadable answer IMHO